# Email reports from cruisecontrol?

Tags: testing, cruisecontrol

Is there a way to have cruisecontrol to email test result in through the config file? C:\Program Files\cruisecontrol\test-output\index.html

This is my current publish setting in the config.xml:

```
 <publishers>
        <currentbuildstatuspublisher file="${log.dir}/status.txt"/>
        <htmlemail
    buildresultsurl="http://${build.server}/buildresults/${project.name}"
            subjectprefix="[CruiseControl] " 
            xsldir="${cruise.install.dir}/webapps/cruisecontrol/xsl"
    css="${cruise.install.dir}/webapps/cruisecontrol/css/cruisecontrol.css"
            logdir="${log.dir}"
            mailhost="mailhost" defaultsuffix="@myemail.com" reportsuccess="always"
            returnaddress="${return.email}"
    >
    <always address="${team.email}"/>
    </htmlemail>
 </publishers>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to include it using the [fileMerge](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/File+Merge+Task) task, something like this:

```
<publishers>
  <merge>
    <files>
      <file>C:\Project\test-output\emailable-report.html</file>
      <file><!-- path --></file>
    </files>
  </merge>
</publishers>
```

Edit: Assuming the file is XML based...

Comment: thanks, what would the path for the 2nd file be? anywhere I want?

Comment: just any other files you want to be merged into the email, so in your case, you could exclude it.  If you had Fit tests, you would put the path to the fitnesse output as one of the <file> parameters